# Weird UEFI macbook

Tags: macos, ubuntu, uefi, macbook-pro, macbook

Assuming that all modern macs come with EFI, I have installed Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro (15", late 13), alongside OSX.

When I turn the device on, it boots into Ubuntu. When I hold down the option key, I only get the option "Macintosh HD" which boots into OSX.

efibootmgr says:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e07bd003-42d6-409f-abff-41ecbfdafac6,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,b777f8c5-13b7-4de3-8e4f-639a9bada436,0x74678048,0x136000)
Boot0081* Recovery OS   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,b777f8c5-13b7-4de3-8e4f-639a9bada436,0x74678048,0x136000)/File(\com.apple.recovery.boot\boot.efi)
Boot0082*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,b777f8c5-13b7-4de3-8e4f-639a9bada436,0x6fd38b08,0x136000)
```

The EFI boot partition contains both bootloaders for Ubuntu and OSX. 
As far as I understand, the EFI can find the different OS (and the Recovery OS).

Why can't I choose between the two OS when starting the computer with the option key (which invokes the EFI bootselector as far as I understand)?

Comment: I'm not compleately sure, but I think it's because `Ubuntu` is under `Boot0000` and the rest are incrementing up starting at `Boot0080`

Comment: It might also be because of it not calling `PciRoot`